# Can we monitoring and ranging unknown Beacons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ibeacon

By looking in the API of CLLocationManager for Beacon, it seems that we can only monitoring and ranging known Beacons. It means, our application must know all UUID of Beacons to monitor.

Is it possible to monitor an unknown Beacon? So we can dynamically add new Beacons in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It means, our application must know all UUID of Beacons to monitoring.

Yes, that's right.

> Is it possible to monitor an unknown Beacon?

No, iOS doesn't provide a mechanism to find beacons that you don't know about.

> So we can dynamically add new Beacons in the list.

You can certainly change the set of beacons that you're monitoring; you just need some way to find out about them first. For example, your app could periodically pull a list of known beacon ID's from your server. What you cannot do is scan for *all* beacons in proximity of the device. In short, you need a beacon's UUID in order to monitor it.

Many beacons can share the same UUID, so it's not like your app needs prior knowledge of every individual beacon that you might use. If you add another beacon with the same UUID to the environment, any existing app that knows about the UUID will be able to find the new beacon.

Comment: @op plz note: that apple doesn't allow users to edit the UUID -- the UUID must be in the app and you can't let the user enter UUIDs he wants to scan

Comment: I don't think that we will have problem with adding UUID by users. However, this use-case is not common.